# How to detect power button press in a service Android Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

***Context*** --- I am developing a app where i have a foreground service that detects a shake event and then sends a sms. But to minimize false positives I want to make it so that when the shakeevent has happened, I want to check that was the power button pressed at that time and only then send the sms.

Basic idea is that user would have to hold the power button of phone and then shake to trigger the event instead of just a normal shake.

Here is the code where i detect the shake event.

```
mShakeDetector!!.setOnShakeListener(object : ShakeDetector.OnShakeListener {
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        override fun onShake(count: Int) {
            // check if the user has shacked
            // the phone for 3 time in a row
            if (count == 3) {

                // vibrate the phone
                vibrate()

                //here i want to call the sendSos method that is in the mainActivity
                sendMessage()
                //Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Shaken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

    })
```

Here when the shake is registered 3 times, the sms is sent but I want to make it so that when the shake count becomes 3 i want to check that at that time is the power button pressed if that is pressed then send the sms.

Here is the pseudocode for better understanding.

```
fun shakDetect(count){
    if (count==3){
        if(powerButtonPressed==true){
            sendSOS()
        }
    }
}
```